# How to select the next free cell in a row in Google Sheets using Google Script/Google Sheets Macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let me just just say that I am brand new to Google Scripts and Google Macros, so please excuse my ignorance here... Haha.

I've dug through this site and have found many similar questions, but not one that solves my specific issue.

Basically, I'm using a macro to copy a full column from one sheet to another, pasting starting at D3.

We have 'week' columns across the top, so each week I need it to paste one cell to the right. Basically, checking if D3 is empty, and if so, paste. If not, check E3, etc.

Here's what recording the macro gave me:

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C:C').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('2023 Audits'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Dashboard!C:C').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

So I need `spreadsheet.getRange('D3').activate();` to be modified so that if D3 contains text, it pastes in E3. If E3 contains, text, it pastes F3. And so on. (As each week we move one column to the right.)

(I'd like to start checking from D3 as every 10-12 weeks we'll be archiving results, and the new week would once again start from D3.)

Apologies if this is a simple question, but any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks so much!
John

Answer (score 1):

IMO for these dynamic features you will have to get little deeper into the Google Apps Script. Recording macros and modifying them won't be enough.

This is script I wrote for you to help you to get to your goal + understand what's going on. I broke it down to smaller pieces and put logs everywhere, the code is longer but it should be instructive.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const sourceValues = getSourceValues_(ss);
  Logger.log(`sourceValues=${JSON.stringify(sourceValues)}`);


  const destinationColumnNumber = getDestinationColumnNumber_(ss);
  Logger.log(`destinationColumnNumber=${JSON.stringify(destinationColumnNumber)}`);

  copyValues_(ss, sourceValues, destinationColumnNumber)
}


function getSourceValues_(ss) {
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  const startRow = 1;
  const endRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();

  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 3, endRow - startRow + 1, 1);
  const sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  return sourceValues;
}

function getDestinationColumnNumber_(ss) {
  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("2023 Audits");

  const row3Range = destinationSheet.getRange("3:3");
  const row3Values = row3Range.getValues();
  Logger.log(`row3Values=${JSON.stringify(row3Values)}`);

  const row3ValuesArray = row3Values[0];
  Logger.log(`row3ValuesArray=${JSON.stringify(row3ValuesArray)}`);

  for (let i = 3; i < row3ValuesArray.length; i++) {
    if (row3ValuesArray[i] == "") {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }

}

function copyValues_(ss, sourceValues, destinationColumnNumber) {
  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("2023 Audits");

  const destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(3, destinationColumnNumber, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length);
  destinationRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Using the entire column "C:C" can lead to problems when your data grows, try to use the data-filled ranges.

Disclaimer: I coded this with plenty assumptions, I can't know if you can have gaps in data, empty cells, not enough columns etc. You can see and test the code [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tc1jJ-TpGuv9VQdfJkNDTH432rv_mOfItd8Ryw0edwY/edit#gid=0).

Welcome to the Google Apps Script coding.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back. This is amazing! I won't be able to implement this until Monday, but I truly appreciate the time and effort you put into putting this together! Yes, I'm just getting started with Google Apps Script and am starting to realize the limitations of macros. This will be a great first project for me to get my feet wet. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('2023 Audits');
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  ssh.getRange("C1:C" + ssh.getLastRow()).copyTo(dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 4), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back!

When I use the code as written it pastes the column way down in the D column, instead of in the J column as seen here: https://share.getcloudapp.com/DOul5nR9

Comment: Based upon your code that's where I thought you wanted it.  Where do you want it?   I'm not in the habit of following unknown links